# Concatenate CSV files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, concatenation

l have csv files to concatenate. l have three files l want to concatenate. The number of columns is the same so the desired output will have also the same columns

file1.csv

```
id                                       ocr    raw_value   manual_raw_value
2a909d6e-5eb2-49a1-b6e8-171bf01dafdc    ABBYY   7,20         7,20
0c93bc55-2c42-4afb-8428-c12736b0a86e    ABBYY   44            44
12973bd0-72c7-4333-ac8d-ab0f18e33cb0    OMNIPAGE    4578     4578
2ccbeb11-ed0d-49a3-a321-a1c583764e3d    ABBYY        1             1
f78636d7-c22f-4a85-bb34-fd8757352ec5    ABBYY   8040.56     8040.56
2d1c5869-1f87-4b47-bbf4-c2f31b122c0b    OMNIPAGE    6        6
2d914f73-39d9-4108-8467-4d7a28933aa6    OMNIPAGE    0         0
```

File2

```
id                                        ocr   raw_value   manual_raw_value
bfa6c9f1-89c0-486b-a85c-a97a370a92c4    OMNIPAGE    35470       35470
213e1e1e-29df-44c2-acee-79f7fefa7ba9    OMNIPAGE    Echeance    Ech√©ance
1ebecadc-056b-41c8-8426-446fff6bad71    OMNIPAGE    Etoblissemenls  Etablissements
35c1b736-f504-487d-a531-3b133045139e    OMNIPAGE    :               :
009ee382-c1f2-4194-92e1-9b9fffd387d2    OMNIPAGE    1087         1087
35dd36a6-7c9c-4f81-b3f7-db6533bd159f    OMNIPAGE    1              1
218f6860-b6aa-4bba-b64a-c2cc0b40812b    OMNIPAGE    HT               HT
```

File3

```
id                                        ocr   raw_value   manual_raw_value
4a82a357-99e7-49e6-85b6-b2f6a27b8d5f    OMNIPAGE    Terms   Terms
8b549fef-0cda-4af5-8239-35153c33ffbc    OMNIPAGE    price   price
52ffe66a-b1ab-4b22-9b26-c298d53c951c    OMNIPAGE    Renseignements  
 Renseignements
507a0d96-9481-4b3f-8c35-f16588bedc0b    OMNIPAGE    pour    pour
52e171dc-8d22-4162-b748-692b2fc11659    OMNIPAGE    Client  Client
c40a7e9f-1ec4-4cac-87e8-02ed0f335fe9    OMNIPAGE    5   5
4a936ed7-c082-4f46-9fa1-761a1525e2df    OMNIPAGE    SAS SAS
4b78130e-b099-400c-b7bf-6470e0519783    OMNIPAGE    des des
4d5c6297-1c79-42f9-b4ea-929a9abfb3f7    OMNIPAGE    431 431
829d8bf5-b251-4bb1-82d8-0e912ab64e8e    OMNIPAGE    59  59
```

Desired output

```
         id                                      ocr    raw_value   manual_raw_value

        2a909d6e-5eb2-49a1-b6e8-171bf01dafdc    ABBYY   7,20         7,20
        0c93bc55-2c42-4afb-8428-c12736b0a86e    ABBYY   44            44
        12973bd0-72c7-4333-ac8d-ab0f18e33cb0    OMNIPAGE    4578     4578
        2ccbeb11-ed0d-49a3-a321-a1c583764e3d    ABBYY        1             1
        f78636d7-c22f-4a85-bb34-fd8757352ec5    ABBYY   8040.56     8040.56
        2d1c5869-1f87-4b47-bbf4-c2f31b122c0b    OMNIPAGE    6        6
        2d914f73-39d9-4108-8467-4d7a28933aa6    OMNIPAGE    0         0

        bfa6c9f1-89c0-486b-a85c-a97a370a92c4    OMNIPAGE    35470       35470
        213e1e1e-29df-44c2-acee-79f7fefa7ba9    OMNIPAGE    Echeance    Ech√©ance
        1ebecadc-056b-41c8-8426-446fff6bad71    OMNIPAGE    Etoblissemenls  Etablissements
        35c1b736-f504-487d-a531-3b133045139e    OMNIPAGE    :               :
        009ee382-c1f2-4194-92e1-9b9fffd387d2    OMNIPAGE    1087         1087
        35dd36a6-7c9c-4f81-b3f7-db6533bd159f    OMNIPAGE    1              1
        218f6860-b6aa-4bba-b64a-c2cc0b40812b    OMNIPAGE    HT               HT
        4a82a357-99e7-49e6-85b6-b2f6a27b8d5f    OMNIPAGE    Terms   Terms
        8b549fef-0cda-4af5-8239-35153c33ffbc    OMNIPAGE    price   price
        52ffe66a-b1ab-4b22-9b26-c298d53c951c    OMNIPAGE    Renseignements  
         Renseignements
        507a0d96-9481-4b3f-8c35-f16588bedc0b    OMNIPAGE    pour    pour
        52e171dc-8d22-4162-b748-692b2fc11659    OMNIPAGE    Client  Client
        c40a7e9f-1ec4-4cac-87e8-02ed0f335fe9    OMNIPAGE    5   5
        4a936ed7-c082-4f46-9fa1-761a1525e2df    OMNIPAGE    SAS SAS
        4b78130e-b099-400c-b7bf-6470e0519783    OMNIPAGE    des des
        4d5c6297-1c79-42f9-b4ea-929a9abfb3f7    OMNIPAGE    431 431
        829d8bf5-b251-4bb1-82d8-0e912ab64e8e    OMNIPAGE    59  59
```

Here is my code

```
import os
import glob
import pandas

def concatenate(indir,outputfile):
    os.chdir(indir)
    fileList=glob.glob("*.csv")
    dfList=[]
    colnames=["id","ocr","raw_value","manual_raw_value"]
    for filename in fileList:
        print(filename)
        df=pandas.read_csv(input,header=None)
        dfList.append(df)
    concatenateDF=pandas.concat(dfList,axis=0)
    concatenateDF.columns=colnames
    concatenateDF.to_save(outputfile,index=None)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input="/files"
    output="files/concatenated.csv"
    concatenate(input,output)
```

l get the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ahmed/crnn/concatenate_files.py", line 21, in <module>
    concatenate(input,output)
  File "/home/ahmed/crnn/concatenate_files.py", line 12, in concatenate
    df=pandas.read_csv(input,header=None)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 646, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 389, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 730, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 923, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1390, in __init__
words2.csv
    self._reader = _parser.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 538, in pandas.parser.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/parser.c:6171)
pandas.io.common.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

What's wrong with my code ?

How can l solve that?

Thank you

Comment: Your code went wrong at line 21:df=pandas.read_csv(input,header=None).I guess it's a problem with your file data format. Maybe you should set 'sep='.

Comment: hi @giser_yugang, thank you, l tried that but l get the same error

Comment: If one of our answers worked, you could mark the best one accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your csv has uneven spacing. This can be handled easily. When reading in your data, set `delim_whitespace=True`.

```
In [1335]: list_ = []
      ...: for file in glob.glob('*.csv'):
      ...:     df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, delim_whitespace=True)
      ...:     print('Size:', len(df))
      ...:     list_.append(df)
      ...:     
Size: 7
Size: 7
Size: 10
```

The size of each dataframe has been printed. Next, we'll concatenate them as you have done and then assign columns at the end:

```
In [1336]: df = pd.concat(list_, axis=0)

In [1337]: df.columns = ["id", "ocr", "raw_value", "manual_raw_value"]

In [1338]: df.head()
Out[1338]: 
                                     id       ocr raw_value manual_raw_value
0  2a909d6e-5eb2-49a1-b6e8-171bf01dafdc     ABBYY      7,20             7,20
1  0c93bc55-2c42-4afb-8428-c12736b0a86e     ABBYY        44               44
2  12973bd0-72c7-4333-ac8d-ab0f18e33cb0  OMNIPAGE      4578             4578
3  2ccbeb11-ed0d-49a3-a321-a1c583764e3d     ABBYY         1                1
4  f78636d7-c22f-4a85-bb34-fd8757352ec5     ABBYY   8040.56          8040.56
```

Confirm they have been concatenated properly:

```
In [1339]: len(df)
Out[1339]: 24
```

`24 = 7 + 7 + 10`, so you're good to go.

Comment: @Hi COLDSPEED, thank you for your answer. l did what you've said but l got an error at  df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, delim_whitespace=True) as follow :   File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1508, in read     data = self._reader.read(nrows)   File "pandas/parser.pyx", line 848, in pandas.parser.TextReader.read (pandas/parser.c:10415)   F

Comment: @vincent Use this:   `df = pd.read_csv(file, index_col=None, header=0, delim_whitespace=True, error_bad_lines=False)`

Comment: @COLDSPEED, l  get this  File "/home/ahmed/anaconda3/envs/cv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2802, in set_axis
    (old_len, new_len))
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 4 elements

Comment: @vincent It always tends to happen. The data you post and the data you're working with are completely different. As such, a solution for this data cannot be applied to yours without more information on your actual data. Please look at how to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Actually they are the same data

Answer (score 0):

Your error is not due to concatenation as mentioned here:

```
  File "/home/ahmed/crnn/concatenate_files.py", line 12, in concatenate
df=pandas.read_csv(input,header=None)
```

You have unequally spaced columns in your file, the separation between the columns have to be consistent. This question is irrelevant to the error you are getting. I guess, you must have copied the print out of a dataframe from some text.

For example, in file1.csv the number of space between the raw_value and manual_value columns

line#1 is 9

```
2a909d6e-5eb2-49a1-b6e8-171bf01dafdc    ABBYY   7,20         7,20
```

in line#2 is 12

```
0c93bc55-2c42-4afb-8428-c12736b0a86e    ABBYY   44            44
```

Comment: Hi @tiba,   "You have unequally spaced columns in your file, the separation between the columns have to be consistent" what do you mean by that

Comment: As @COLDSPEED answered your question, they spaces between the columns.